# Automatic project references update in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

Are you tired of checking if a newer version of the library you're using has been released, or when you update to new versions, change all references in all csproj projects?

For example, I have many csproj projects using those references:

```
     <HintPath>..\..\..\Referencias Externas\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary 4.1\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.dll</HintPath>  
    ...more...more...    
    <HintPath>..\..\..\Referencias Externas\Unity 1.2\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll</HintPath>
    ...more...more...  
     <HintPath>..\..\..\Referencias\Company\2.0\Company.Common.dll</HintPath>
```

Now, I would like use new versions, EnterpriseLibrary 5.0, Unity 2.1, NHibernate 3.2, etc, and references to Company Framework (Company.Common.dll, etc), but I need changes all references in many,many projects.

any extension in VS2010 for do it easy and quick?

I would like any like ProjectConverter - Auto update DevExpress references   http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q308968.aspx

Reference:
http://feedback.wovs.com/forums/71955-extension-ideas/suggestions/1003595-automatic-reference-update

Comment: Use [nuget](http://nuget.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the package manager [nuget](http://nuget.org/) to manage your dependencies.

> NuGet is a Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to install and update third-party libraries and tools in Visual Studio.

Comment: Nuget is better, but in my case now I would like any like ProjectConverter - Auto update DevExpress references. I have third references and company framework references, are private references for company, not possible publish in nuget I think.

Comment: @Kiquenet - You can setup a company NuGet server.

Comment: @Kiquenet - http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could create a library project that does the handling and forwards access to the .dlls and every other project uses this one.  Then you only need to update the .dll references in this one wrapper project.

Comment: For me, that's impossible, using Infraestructure references like EntLib Logging - Exception, Unity, and to NHibernate, Automapper, ODP.net, and Company Framework references.